# Add Firebase gcm to project

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to add Firebase to my project to use push notifications

at home I implemented it by adding this line at build.gradle (app)

```
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this line at my build.gradel (project):

```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and it worked .

At work for proxy reasons i'm not able to connect to jcenter and getting this error :

```
Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
```

so i cant build the project

I need a way to implement this without the plugin and classpath

I'm using

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

my depndecies :
    dependencies {

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

And is there a way to add the play-services classes to the gradel cash to be able to work offline

NOTE:
I have tried to update to sdk 24 and build tool 24.0.3
and not use thouse tow lines but i kept geting the error that fire base was never initialized and i need to use this:

```
firebase.initializeApp(context)
```

I did use in the application context but did not work

NOTE 2 :
My build.gradel (project) has jcenter as a repository

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
```

Comment: Firebase and Google Play services libraries are in Google Repository in your Android SDK Manager. They're on your local drive. However you need `jcenter()` (or sometimes just `mavenCentral()`) repository for any other libraries. Adjust your proxy settings as suggested. Contact your network administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in build.gradle(project)

```
  repositories {
        jcenter()
 }
```

Comment: It's added @Rissmon